# What directories (folders) does Arduino expect, and how are they created?

Tags: arduino, directory

I am running Linux Fedora 12 (I know ...) The tutorials for Arduino talk of a bewildering and often conflicting  set of folders ("folders"? a Windows term?), such as "target" "sketchbook" and "libraries". What is the recommended structure of the Arduino directory, which of these should be generated automatically, and which should I create as empty directories? After trying a few experiments, this is the sorry state of my ~/arduino/ directory.

```
 ... ~]$ ls -l arduino/
total 31816
-rw-rw-r--.  1 Harry Harry   284277 2012-08-18 16:07 191789-an-01-en-   ARDUINO_UNO_PLATINE.pdf
-rw-rw-r--.  1 Harry Harry  1413564 2012-10-29 15:11 2-2-tft-display.pdf
drwxr-xr-x. 10  1000  1000     4096 2012-08-28 15:51 arduino-1.0.1
-rw-rw-r--.  1 Harry Harry 15715667 2012-08-13 15:17 arduino-1.0.1-linux.tgz
-rw-rw-r--.  1 Harry Harry    70114 2012-10-08 16:16 ArduinoI2CSlave.pdf
-rw-rw-r--.  1 Harry Harry    36395 2012-09-01 16:15 Arduino playground - TimedAction  Library.html
-rw-rw-r--.  1 Harry Harry   450230 2012-09-01 13:56 ArduinoUno_R3_Pinouts.png
-rw-rw-r--.  1 Harry Harry    83339 2012-09-02 11:52 Arduino_Uno_Rev3-schematic.pdf
-rw-rw-r--.  1 Harry Harry 13133105 2012-08-19 11:18 doc8161.pdf
-rw-rw-r--.  1 Harry Harry    19641 2012-09-01 13:55 Electronics   Microprocessors       Arduino Uno Rev3 pinouts photo.html
-rw-rw-r--.  1 Harry Harry    24305 2012-09-07 14:47 Hardware   Neil's Log Book.html
-rw-r--r--.  1 root  root     75220 2012-10-08 17:56 I2CSlave.bklt
drwxrwxr-x.  3 Harry Harry     4096 2012-08-18 17:13 LCDtutorial
drwxrwxr-x.  3 Harry Harry     4096 2011-10-15 03:04 __MACOSX
-rw-rw-r--.  1 Harry Harry  1134034 2012-08-19 16:23    nRF24L01P_Product_Specification_1_0.pdf
-rw-rw-r--.  1 Harry Harry     4422 2012-08-29 15:12 NRF24Library.html
drwxr-xr-x. 40 Harry Harry     4096 2011-12-09 12:01 Programming Arduino
-rw-rw-r--.  1 Harry Harry    24302 2012-08-18 14:37 ProgrammingArduino1.0.zip
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root  root      4096 2012-09-01 15:55 sketchaug28a
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root  root      4096 2012-09-01 19:53 sketchaug28b
-rw-rw-r--.  1 Harry Harry    41684 2012-10-08 11:39 SlaveI2C.txt
drwxr-xr-x.  3 Harry Harry     4096 2006-05-12 10:09 Test
-rw-rw-r--.  1 Harry Harry     3109 2012-10-30 18:38 Test.zip
```

I'll be grateful for any advice on how to tidy this up in an Arduino canonical form, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the `arduino-1.0.1` folder should be a folder `library`. The sketchbook is by default located in the `/home/{username}` folder. I also don't know about a folder called `target`.

Comment: Thank you. I see that I have a "sketchbook" directory in /home/Harry, as you say. My real problem is: should have I found that the system had placed the "library" directory in "arduino", in which case something has gone wrong, or is it one I should have created myself. None of the "get you started" stuff says which. Also I see both "library" and "libraries" quoted, is it both or which?

Comment: When I downloaded the arduino-sdk, the libraries folder was included in the zip-file. On both my machines, Windows and Linux, the folder is called "libraries".

Comment: Thank you again, that was very helpful. Now it seems obvious (and maybe I was a bit silly). I had downloaded the .tgz file into a directory called "arduino" in my home directory and did the install there, so I found the "libraries" in another "arduino" directory within that. I have now deleted it all and moved the .tgz to my home directory, installed from it there, and now all is ok. I live to learn, thank you again for your patient help.

Comment: I have found, by Googling, and by comparing what I got with Sketch->Import in Arduino, that my new libraries have to be in <my home directory>/arduino-1.0.1/libraries, not in <my home directory>/sketchbook/libraries, in order for them to show up in the Sketch->Import list. I haven't tried to use them yet to see if this works in a program (sketch), so i would be grateful for any comments on this.

Comment: Now I have discovered that, looking in "Preferences" in the "File" tab that I did not have <my home directory>/sketchbook as the "sketchbook location". I corrected this, and now the downloaded libraries in there do show up in the Sketch->Import list.

Comment: Well at last I have got a demonstration program (sketch) running on my Adafruit 2.2in 18-bit color TFT LCD display. so this will be my last comment on this matter.